# laravel/carbon date format, incorrect formatting

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

I have a blade where I'm pulling list of dates through a variable in a controller. It's pulling the dates successfully but it displays as `12082017` as opposed to `12/08/2017` like I want.

I added this:

```
<td style="color: #ff0000;">{{ \Carbon\Carbon::create($psku->avail_date)->toDateString() }}
```

But unfortunately it looks to be appending today's date to the date string I'm accessing so it looks like this `12082017-11-07`

How can I use laravel/carbon to pull the dates of the variable and add the slashes like I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your date `12082017` to format like this `2017-08-12` then you can do that using `createFromFormat` function.

```
<td style="color: #ff0000;">{{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('dmY', $psku->avail_date)->toDateString() }}
```

> For more info visit
>   http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-instantiation

Comment: Thank you, but it's giving me an error that it failed to parse time string (12082017 at position 7)

Comment: Modified answer. Let me know if that works or not. I suppose this should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

First parse the created_at field as Carbon object. Then format it.

```
<td style="color: #ff0000;">{{ \Carbon\Carbon::parse($psku->avail_date)->format('Y-m-d') }}
```

You can format is your own way

```
format('d/m/Y').
```

Comment: Thank you, but it's giving me an error that it failed to parse time string (12082017 at position 7)

Comment: which format data contains $psku->avail_date ? echo $psku->avail_date and check how data looks like.

Comment: it looks like ```12082017```. It's just a number string pulled from the database. Today is the first time I've used carbon and only in this line, but the data is coming from certain dates in the database. I need to just add slashes after 2nd and 4th character

Comment: It may not be possible as far as i know to convert raw data 12082017 to format that you expect. It should be date format. If you insert date from input then use <input type="text" pattern="\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}" class="datepicker" name="avail_date" value="" /> that force user to insert date format.

Comment: I'm afraid I won't have that option. This variable is just storing the string from the database so there's no input associated with it

Comment: In first time how you get this data 12082017 in your database ?